# Spring boot instantiate multiple components

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, callable

I have a callable type class. It is a annotated with @component. I would like to create multiple instances of the callable class. To do so, I am using the application context. The problem is it simply does not work.

Comment: by default spring beans are `Singleton`. did you change the scope of the bean?

Comment: "To do so, I am using the application context" what is that suppose to mean?

Comment: Create a `@Configuration` class to act as a factory. Have a method annotated `@Bean @Scope(“prototype”)` which returns a new instance. Inject your factory where you want to create them and call the annotated method.

Comment: Can you please mention what did not work and if possible please add some code

Answer (score 1):

Refer Bean scope you want to use:
[https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#:~:text=2%20The%20prototype%20scope,method%20call%20on%20the%20container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#:%7E:text=2%20The%20prototype%20scope,method%20call%20on%20the%20container)).

1. singleton - once for each IoC container, your application context
2. prototype- multiple beans for multiple object instance
3. request - in case of web aware app context, each bean to a particular HTTP request, and new instance for another
4. session- for each HTTP session.
5. global session - as what name says.

depending on your use select scope as well explained by @BeUndead.